# c++ operator overloading in template class Im trying to build an overloading << for printing the tree

Tags: c++, class, templates, syntax, compiler-errors

```js
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;


template<class T> 
class BinarySearchTree {
public:
 BinarySearchTree() {
  root = NULL;
 };

 class Node{
 public:
  Node* left;
  Node* right;
  Node* parent;
  T data;
 };
 Node* root;
 int Size(Node*);
 void insert(T);
 bool Exsist(T);
 void PrintTree(Node*);
 T Size();
 bool isEmpty() const {
  return root==NULL;
 }
 template < class T>
 friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Node& a);
 
};


template <class T>
void BinarySearchTree<T>::insert(T d)
{
 Node* t = new Node;
 Node* parent;
 t->data = d;
 t->right = NULL;
 t->left = NULL;
 parent = NULL;
 if(isEmpty())
  root = t;
 else
 {
  Node* curr;
  curr = root;
  while(curr)
  {
   parent = curr;
   if(t->data > curr->data)
    curr = curr->right;
   else
    curr = curr->left;
  }

  if(t->data < parent->data)
   parent->left = t;
  else
   parent->right = t;
 }
}


template <class T>
bool BinarySearchTree<T>::Exsist(T d)
{
 bool found = NULL;
 Node* curr = root;
 while(curr != NULL && !found)
 {
  if( d == curr->data )
  {
  cout << "The number is in the tree" << endl;
  found = true;
  }
  else if( d > curr->data)
   curr = curr->right;
  else if(d < curr->data)
   curr = curr->left;
 }
 if( !found )
  cout << "The number not found" << endl;
 return found;
}


template <class T>
int BinarySearchTree<T>::Size(Node* a)
{
  if (a == NULL) return 0;
 else
  return(1 + Size(a->left) + Size(a->right));

}

template < class T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Node& a) //line 102
{
    PrintTree(a);
 os << endl;
 return os;
}

template <class T>
void BinarySearchTree<T>::PrintTree(Node* tree)
{
 if (tree!=NULL) {
  cout << tree->data << ", " ;
  PrintTree(tree->right);
  PrintTree(tree->left);
  
 }
}
```

-Edit-
I've changed it and now there is an error only on the implementation

Error   1   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int 102
Error   2   error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&'  102

Comment: There is no template called `Node`, so any reference to `Node<T>` it immediately wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it but there still an errors

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error on the declaration and Implementation the overloaded operator use this instead

```
template < class T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Node<T>& a);
```

in declaration and implementation.

Comment: There are no template `Node`

Comment: I tryed it too, & it didn't work, I add it to the code above